# Allow only certain routes in Devise authentication

Tags: facebook, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using Devise omniauth to authenticate users through Facebook.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

This works well, but I want to restrict users from accessing 'http://app/users/sign_in' page

I can change the routes as following:

```
devise_scope :user do 
  match '/users/auth/facebook/callback' => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#facebook'
end
```

But then how do I redirect users not to get unpleasant messages from controllers that have

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

What I want is for users to use only devise_scope matching url, otherwise redirect them always to some default 'application#index' route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest devise versions will always redirect you to the root_url page when using just omniauth and not using database_authenticatable. You can customize that by generating a route with "new_user_session" as name pointing to your "application#index".

Comment: Thanks! Modified routes file `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" } do
    get 'users/sign_in' => 'application#about', :as => :new_user_session
  end` and also had to remove User models devise :validatable option since password field is not necessary when using only omniauth option.